# check for null url before launching webactivity

Tags: android, if-statement, null

I'm trying to check for a null url before launching webactivity. In the listactivty, when an item is selected, if no url is found it should display a toast otherwise if a url is found it should launch webactivity. This is the code I've written

```
if (txtUrl == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "No further information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (txtUrl != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        WebActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", txtUrl.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Problem is that webactivity is launched whether or not url is null

Comment: Are you treating `null` and `<empty>` as the same state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probabbly want to check **this string**

```
txtUrl.getText().toString()
```

against `emptyness`.
Not **this object**

```
txtUrl
```

against `null`.

So, you should perform **this** check:

```
if(txtUrl.getText().toString().isEmpty()){...
```

Comment: altered the code but it seems to be implemented selectively, when the string is empty, sometimes it displays toast and other times it launches webactivity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if the string is empty.

```
if(texturl.isEmpty()){
    #Do stuff
}else{
    #Do other stuff
}
```